# Laravel 5.0, using where like with integer not work and not much sense with string

Tags: mysqli, laravel-5

I've try to use where and like conditional on phone number or digital number actually this query will retrieved all the rows in my tables even those field is empty.

```
  $cont = ClientCbcContact::where('contact_number_number', 'like', '%'.Request::input('phone').'%')->get();
```

However I use with string as below to retrieve my **family_name** which contain data **heng sopheak, heng2 sopheak, heng, heng sopheak4 ** and **Request::input('name')=** equal to heng sopheak. it select only one rows name **heng sopheak**.

```
ClientCbcGeneral::where('family_name', 'like', '%'. Request::input('name') .'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL LIKE queries require a string, not an integer, you could try casting the number to a string before performing the query.